# TeXShop screen vibration when swiping to scroll down

Tags: texshop

I believe this is off-topic but perhaps someone can help me...

Days ago I bought a new computer (a 2015 Macbook Pro) and installed MacTeX and TeXShop on it. One of my old habits in TeXShop is making a big swipe to jump to the bottom or the top of a short document, or to quickly check if I am at the bottom of a document. It used to scroll with "inertia" until the display was somewhere below the last line of the file and then smoothly track back until the last line was at the bottom of the window. Now, though, when I do it the source text hits the bottom abruptly and vibrates jaggedly. It's a small issue, but old habits die hard, and it has really been making my eyes hurt. Does anyone know what's wrong or how to fix it? (I'm using TeXShop version 3.58.)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This is off-topic!

Comment: If this is an issue specific to TeXshop you should try to alarm the developers about this (maybe [here](http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/)), if it is a general issue for all applications, you might ask over at [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/).